# datatypes in sql server , difference between similar dataypes, numeric, money , decimal ,float

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

What datatypes could be given to this value --> 45.58

Could these be given:

- numeric
- money
- decimal
- float

What's the difference then? Which one would be the best to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like everything else in SQL Server, **it depends**.

`Numeric` is the same as `Decimal`.  These let you specify precision and are good if you will be having more than 2 decimal places or need more precision than what you indicated.

`Money` is used for, you guessed it, money.  If your field is a currency this is appropriate.

`Float` is kind of special and is **NOT** suited for exact numbers.  If you need to represent floating point numbers, this is a way to go.  If you need to always store exactly what you put in the field, `float` is a bad choice.

**So, what do you want to use the field for?  What does your data actually represent?**  That should be the determining factor in what datatype you use.

Answer (score 3):

`numeric` and `decimal` are the same thing. They store fixed-precision decimal values. You specify precision and scale (e.g. `decimal(8,3)` specifies that the field is 8 decimal digits in width and the last 3 digits are right of the decimal point).

`Money` is similar to numeric/decimal, except that its scale is fixed: it stores 4 decimal points of precision. The underlying data store is, I believe, a signed 64-bit two's complement integer. The decimal point is implied. `Smallmoney` is a signed 32-bit two's complement integer with an implied 4 decimal places of precision. Despite the name, money/smallmoney aren't just for currency values: if you don't need a ginormous range or high precision, money/small money are your best choices, IMHO. Storage is more compact than the equivalent decimal/numeric value.

`float` is IEEE floating point. It comes with all advantages and disadvantages possessed by all floating point values. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

I don't believe that any particular format is somehow more better than another: it depends on your needs and the tradeoffs inherent in all of these (decimal/numeric, for instance, chew up a relatively lot of space). There's nothing to stop you from rolling your own, either: you could, for instance, store your `45.58` value as an integer (4558), for instance. Anybody using the field, of course, would need to know that it has an implied scale of 2.